# Unable to Embed redirect using Ternary operator in JSX

Tags: reactjs, redirect, jsx, conditional-operator

I am using Firefox 83.0
I am trying to write a basic redirect using react but every time I use the turnery operator I get an error that shows that I am using an unexpected token "**,**" in place of "**?**"[image: error]

You can see the error and the related code in the following screenshot

> I haven't provided the complete code because I don't think it is relevant in this case but do let me know if the code is required

Comment: Can you reproduce in a sandbox?

Comment: @DennisVash I don't know how to do that. Is there sample code or article I can refer to?

Comment: Use codesandbox.com to make a minimal reproducible example, nothing fancy. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash https://kpgrf.csb.app/ , is this the way to share this? Because I tried adding it to the questions as a code snippet, it did not work

Comment: Just remove the `{}`, you define an object, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't JSX, it's JS syntax. Look at what is happening in your code:

1. you have a `return` following a `(` which is valid JS code
2. then you are opening a `{` which tells the JS engine that a object is about to be created.
   Objects structure is `{key: value}`.

So whats happening is the JS engine is telling you that you have a wrong syntax for creating an object.

You should just omit the curly braces `{` and it will work fine

```
return (
   redirect ? <Redirect /> : the rest of the code
)
```

That would have been valid code, if you were using it inside a JSX tag.

```
<div>{isValid ? 'yes': 'no'}</div>
```

Here you are telling the transpiler, that you want to write JS code inside JSX